# Interpretation of a log likelihood function for PROC NLMIXED in SAS

Tags: r, data-transformation, sas, generalized-linear-model, likelihood

I have a data set of skewed nutrient intake values, from around 7800 individuals, of whom around 3000 had two measures of daily nutrient intake (the others only had one measure), so this is a repeated measures design, very unbalanced. The `boxcox` transformation in the `MASS` package in `R` identified a suitable lambda (0.4) to use for the transformation to linearity, and the nutrient value transformation takes the normal Box Cox form of `(x^L-1)/L` where `x` is the nutrient intake value (`&response`) and `L` is lambda (0.4 in this case). The purpose of this transformation is to provide a linear dependent variable for a subsequent `nlmer` analysis in `R` although the original analysis was performed in `SAS`.

`PROC NLMIXED` in `SAS`, unlike other `SAS` procedures, requires a user-specified `MODEL` statement. In the `SAS` code, a general log likelihood function has been provided, which is (rest of `SAS` syntax omitted, the `&` are there as the syntax uses `SAS` macro language):

```
ll1=log(1/(sqrt(2*pi*A_VAR_E)));
ll2=(-(boxcoxy-x2b2u2)**2)/(2*A_VAR_E)+(&amtlambda-1)*log(&response);
ll=ll1+ll2;
model &response ~ general(ll);
```

I can follow some of this log likelihood specification, as I can see some relationship to the [probability density function of the normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). But I don't understand the parameterisation to the dataset at hand. The values are:

1. `A_VAR_E` appears to be the variance of the residuals
2. `boxcoxy` is the BoxCox-transformed values of `&response`
3. `x2b2u2` is the fitted values based on the fixed and random effects in the model (incorporates age, race, weekend intake effects)
4. `&amtlambda` is 0.4 in this case
5. `&response` is the raw nutrient intake value, that was Box Cox transformed to `boxcoxy`, and is the dependent variable in this analysis.

This likelihood function seems to have deviated from the usual form. In particular, I do not understand why `ll2` incorporates `(&amtlambda-1)*log(&response)` into the denominator. What is this part of the likelihood function doing? Why would the dependent variable `&response` be on both sides of the equation in the model statement? In `ll2` the dependent variable appears to be included twice, once as its transformation `boxcoxy` in the numerator and once as its raw value in the denominator.

I would appreciate any help with understanding why this likelihood has been parameterised this way.